# How to connect database from webserver in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

we have webserver for hosting web services.Database(MySQL) Server for database .Both are not in LAN.Can we connect database from webserver without LAN?

What are the process if possible?

Comment: Which part of the problem exactly bothers you? Connection string? Firewalls and networking? How would you connect to a local database, for example?

Comment: two systems are not in LAN then not able to connect to database("ERROR:Unable to connect any local hosts).if booth are at same LAN then database is connecting .it is possible to connect database system from webserver with out LAN.What are the steps?

Comment: Very unclear question free of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both are not in LAN

If the webserver and the DB server are not in the same LAN, then you have to talk to your IT department and ask them to make a proper [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) between them, and configure [firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_pinhole) to let your DB traffic through. If this is not an option, but there is a server in a third LAN which is accessible from both servers, than you may install a [port forwarder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on this third machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the server by IP address:

> MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.100.15;database=databasename;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx");

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to check.

**[Edit] PHP code follows, didn't realize you were using .NET.**

First, what db host string are you using when connecting to the database? If you are using `'localhost'` as your db host, it will not work, since there isn't a database on the same computer as the web server. Your host setting will need to contain the correct IP address/port:

```
define('myDbHost', '192.168.5.1:5000'); // something like that

// or, when creating the connection (I am presuming you're using PHP)
$mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.5.1:5000", "user", "password", "database");
```

Second problem is making sure that this address/port combination is visible to your web server. You have to be able to create a socket from your web server to that port number on your database server. This is more of a system admin problem.

Comment: wonderful.. c# 6.0? :) please check the tags...

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the tag initially. :-D I did wrote I was *presuming* PHP because of mysql. I even looked at @JackHughes' answer and wondered why the heck he wrote a .NET example.